# Im getting "JavaScript critical error at line 692" in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a problem in IE with my `forEach`, it is working in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge but IE is giving me this error.

**Code** :

```
function jsFiltreleme(GelenDeger) {
                    $('#myDiv').html(''); 
                    var cnt = 1;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/Ajax/ContractedServiceAdd2?serviceName=' + GelenDeger.serviceName + '&&cityCode=' + GelenDeger.cityCode + '&&countryCode=' + GelenDeger.countryCode + '&&markCode=' + GelenDeger.markCode + '',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            response.forEach(acente => {  //Problem is Here line 692
                                const $div = $('<div></div>').addClass("well well-sm").attr('style', 'border-style:ridge;');
                                $div.html(`
                           <div class = "numberCircle"> ` + cnt++ + ` </div> <strong>Acente Adı : </strong>  ` + acente.name + `<br>
                            <strong>Yetki :</strong>  ` + acente.category + `<br>
                            <strong>Adresi : </strong> ` + acente.address + `<br>  
                            <strong>Telefon  :</strong> ` + acente.phone + `<br>
                            <a href=\"mailto:`+ acente.email + `\"><strong> >E-Mail Gönder</strong><br>
                            <a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?q= `+ acente.lat + "," + acente.lng + `\"><strong> >Yol tarifi al</strong>
                       `);
                                $("#myDiv").append($div);
                            });
                            if (response.length == 0) {                              
                                alert("Kayıt Bulunamadı");

                            }
                        },
                    });

                }
```

Comment: Which line is 692 ?

Comment: response.forEach(acente => {  //Problem is Here

Comment: error already in top

Answer (score 0):

The [arrow function expression doesn't support IE browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you could change your code as below:

```
        response.forEach(function (acente) { //Problem is Here line 692

        });
        if (response.length == 0) {
            alert("Kayıt Bulunamadı");

        }
```

**Edit**:

> not change this time is say javascript critical error at line 693

This issue is related to the code about the dynamically add html elements. You could build the DOMString first, then insert the string into a div container using the [append method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append). Code like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">

</div>
<script>
    var response= [your response array];
    var cnt = 1;
    response.forEach(function (acente) {
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(acente);
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(textnode);
        var newdiv = "<div class = 'well well-sm' style='border-style:ridge;'><div class = 'numberCircle'> " + cnt++ + " </div> <strong>Acente Adı : </strong> " + acente.name + "<br />" +
            "<strong>Yetki :</strong>  " + acente.category + "<br>" +
            "<strong>Adresi : </strong> " + acente.address + "<br>" +
            "<strong>Telefon  :</strong> " + acente.phone + "<br>" +
            "<a href='mailto:" + acente.email + "'><strong> >E-Mail Gönder</strong>" + "<br/>" +
            "<a href='https://maps.google.com/maps?q= " + acente.lat + "," + acente.lng + "'><strong> >Yol tarifi al</strong>" +
            "</div>"
        $("#output").append(newdiv);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: not change this time is say javascript critical error at line 693